# Fill col value with greatest value of matched keys within another col

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example dataframe:

```
example_df = {
    'parent_text': ['Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen'],
    'child_desc_text': ['orange' ,'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow', 'black', 'silver'],
    'cost': [0 ,1.20, 1.98, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'uid': [12705024 ,12705087, 12705093, 12705087, 12705093, 12705093, 12705024]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(example_df)


0   Pen orange  0.00    12705024
1   Pen red     1.20    12705087
2   Pen green   1.98    12705093
3   Pen brown   0.00    12705087
4   Pen yellow  0.00    12705093
5   Pen black   0.00    12705093
6   Pen silver  0.00    12705024
```

I require `cost` col to populated where matched in `uid` col (greatest value from matches, else remain 0)

Expected output:

```
expected_df = {
    'parent_text': ['Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Pen'],
    'child_desc_text': ['orange' ,'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow', 'black', 'silver'],
    'cost': [0 ,1.20, 1.98, 1.20, 1.98, 1.98, 0],
    'uid': [12705024 ,12705087, 12705093, 12705087, 12705093, 12705093, 12705024]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(example_df)


0   Pen orange  0.00    12705024
1   Pen red     1.20    12705087
2   Pen green   1.98    12705093
3   Pen brown   1.20    12705087
4   Pen yellow  1.98    12705093
5   Pen black   1.98    12705093
6   Pen silver  0.00    12705024
```

I have tried np.where & np.select without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `cost` column with the maximum `cost` of each group by `uid`:

```py
df['cost'] = df.groupby('uid')['cost'].agg(max).loc[df['uid']].to_numpy()
```

**Result:**

```py
  parent_text child_desc_text  cost       uid
0         Pen          orange  0.00  12705024
1         Pen             red  1.20  12705087
2         Pen           green  1.98  12705093
3         Pen           brown  1.20  12705087
4         Pen          yellow  1.98  12705093
5         Pen           black  1.98  12705093
6         Pen          silver  0.00  12705024
```

Comment: Works thank you!,  I am well aware of groupby, can you explain how .loc[df['uid']].to_numpy() works with this?

Comment: @DECROMAX After `... .agg(max)` we get a Series. Its indices are unique `uid`s (there are 3 of them), and elements are the respective max values. When we use `.loc[df['uid']]`, we are selecting the elements of this Series in the exact order as they are in `df['uid']` (so now there are 7 of them). But we can't just assign them to `df['cost']`, because the indices are still `uid`, and the df has indices from 0 to 6. So I converted the Series to a numpy array. Alternatively, you can use `.set_axis(df.index)`  (you can see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73572960/14627505) )

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby().transform('first')` to grab the non-zero value:

```
df['cost'] = (df['cost'].where(df['cost'].ne(0))
              .groupby(df['uid']).transform('first')
              .fillna(df['cost'])
             )
```

Output:

```
  parent_text child_desc_text  cost       uid
0         Pen          orange  0.00  12705024
1         Pen             red  1.20  12705087
2         Pen           green  1.98  12705093
3         Pen           brown  1.20  12705087
4         Pen          yellow  1.98  12705093
5         Pen           black  1.98  12705093
6         Pen          silver  0.00  12705024
```